# Ruby code writing and testing using emac

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, emacs

I want to write my Ruby code using emacs.I am on Ubuntu13.04. I have installed emac using the below commands following [**EmacsHowto**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EmacsHowto):

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get build-dep emacs
sudo apt-get install emacs
```

I am using RVM in my machine. What is the next configuration I need to complete the Ruby configuration?

Please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just seeing emacs for the first time, go through the tutorial (`f1 t`).

The relevant packages for Ruby are `ruby-mode`, `inf-ruby`, `ruby-compilation`.
You can get them through the package manager.
Here are the detailed steps:

1. Open `~/.emacs` and append to it this code:

   ```
   (require 'package)
   (package-initialize)
   (add-to-list
    'package-archives
    '("marmalade" . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/"))
   (add-to-list
    'package-archives
    '("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/"))
   ```
2. Either restart Emacs, or, if you're feeling up to it,
   eval these three expressions. You can eval expression
   by positioning the point behind the last closing paren
   of the expression and pressing <kbd>C-x C-e</kbd>.
3. Open the package manager with <kbd>M-x</kbd> `package-list-packages`.
4. Find for instance, `ruby-mode` with <kbd>C-s</kbd> `ruby-mode`.
   Press <kbd>C-m</kbd> to exit the search.
5. Mark the package that you want for installation with <kbd>m</kbd>
   while the point is on the corresponding line.
6. After you've marked the packages that you want, press <kbd>x</kbd>.
7. Now you can run inferior ruby process inside Emacs with <kbd>M-x</kbd> `run-ruby`.
8. Now when you open `foo.rb` you'll be in `ruby-mode`.
9. When you're in `ruby-mode`, you can source your script with
   <kbd>C-c C-l</kbd> provided inferior ruby is running.

Read info with <kbd>f1 i</kbd>. Info is your friend.

Comment: Can't do it now. It's late here. Maybe tomorrow.

Comment: I open the file *~/.emacs* using [*FindFile*](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FindFile) and save the content using [*Commands for Saving Files*](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Save-Commands.html).

Comment: I got the error `Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading `/home/kirti/.emacs':

Symbol's function definition is void: package-initialize`

Comment: You need `(require 'package)` if your Emacs is old.

Comment: _Do not_ install `ruby-mode` through the package manager. The version that comes with Emacs is better and more up-to-date.